# Determinant of a complex matrix in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, complex-numbers, determinants

Is there a way to calculate the determinant of a complex matrix in PyTroch?

`torch.det` is not implemented for 'ComplexFloat'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not implemented currently. One way would be to implement your own version or simply use `np.linalg.det`.
Here is a short function which computes the determinant of a complex matrix that I wrote using LU-decomposition:

```
def complex_det(A):
    def complex_diag(A):
        return torch.view_as_complex(torch.stack((A.real.diag(), A.imag.diag()),dim=1))
    #Perform LU decomposition to matrix A:
    A_LU, pivots = A.lu()
    P, A_L, A_U = torch.lu_unpack(A_LU, pivots)
    #Det. of multiplied matrices is multiplcation of det.:
    det = torch.prod(complex_diag(A_L)) * torch.prod(complex_diag(A_U)) * torch.det(P.real) #Could probably calculate det(P) [which is +-1] efficiently using Sylvester's determinant identity
    return det
#Test it:
A = torch.view_as_complex(torch.randn(3,3,2))
complex_det(A)
```

Comment: You are right, I have been struggling to write my own version. I'll post it here once done. Thanks Gil.

Comment: I've just updated the post with such version. Check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.8, PyTorch has native support for numpy-style [`torch.linalg`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.8.0/linalg.html) operations. In particular, `torch.linalg.det` has support for `cfloat` and `cdouble` complex number data-types:

```py
torch.linalg.det(input)
```

> Computes the determinant of a square matrix `input`, or of each square matrix in a batched `input`.
>
> **This function supports** float, double, **cfloat and cdouble dtypes.**